# Unable to click on 16th element from sub menu list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Because its lying beneath the page and when we scroll down, then we can see the elements, how to handle this kind of scenarios?

Comment: add your html structure and your code to question too

Comment: Please post your code and error stack trace in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. It will scroll down untill it reaches the given element.

```
public static void scrollToReachAnElement(String xpath){
    try {   

        WebElement element = d.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function of your Selenium driver for scrolling into view

`executeScript(JavaScript code here to scroll down)`

JavaScript code can be

`"arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", your16thWebElement`

Or

`"window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"`

or any other JavaScript code to scroll down